# What happens to those molecules that are not received by receptor proteins on the cell membrane?

Tags: cell-biology, literature, cell-signaling

I am studying cell communication and come to know that proteins from outside environment gets received by receptors on the cellular membrane and then the signal is transduced inside the cell. My question is given a certain concentration of proteins are disseminated in the environment what happens to those protein which are not received by any receptor molecule, **are they denatured and get destroyed in the extracellular environment after some time** in case if the answer is yes **can one provide a reference for the same** Are they bounce back or absorbed by cell membrane?

Comment: For that matter, what about those that _do_ attach to a receptor? Do they stay there forevermore?

Comment: This is a HUGE topic which deserves a comprehensive answer, but here's a basic summary while I have time. 1) often, these signals are degraded over time, e.g. by things the cell secretes [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1783984/]. 2) ligands can attach and unbind repeatedly; mostly they cannot pass through the membrane, though receptor endocytosis can take them into the cell: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receptor-mediated_endocytosis

Comment: Probably some of these things are covered better in more physics- or modeling- oriented textbooks; I have not read it, but I have heard good things about Lauffenberger + Linderman's "Receptors: Models for Binding, Trafficking, and Signaling"

Comment: @AJK the link you mentioned gives this error: The web page address (URL) that you used may be incorrect, can you please provide me reference name or another link?

Comment: It included a bracket by mistake: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1783984/